# web service RemoteException problem

Tags: java

```
    Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.rmi.RemoteException: 
java.rmi.RemoteException:trailing block elements must have an id attribute; 
nested exception is:  trailing block elements must have an id attributeORA-06512:
```

what can caouse this error. Web service is onlnine. Is problem that some attribute changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06512.php

It looks like you are supplying an input value to your call that is larger than the underlying PL/SQL procedure on the server can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an exception is thrown by the logic within the web service you are accessing; no one can really help you diagnose this without being familiar with the inner details of the service you are calling (and it's business logic). I would suggest looking further within the stacktrace. The "ORA-06512" snippet may reveal it is an Oracle-related error.